# What all is in Schema.getGlobalDescribe()?

Tags: apex, schema

what all is returned in that call? i tried debugging it but it was truncated.

Does it tell you for example the names of all your apex classes, VF pages, layouts, recordtypes etc?

Comment: Hi noName, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment and review the [ask] document. In this specific question a very quick search on the SFDC documentation will answer your question better than anybody can do it here.

Answer (score 9):

The method returns a `Map<String, Schema.SObjectType>`. The `String` key is the lower-case `API Name` (though `get` methods on this map are case-insensitive). It contains every object in your org.

You can also debug them one by one:

```
Map<String, SObjectType> sObjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
for (String apiName : sObjects.keySet())
{
    system.debug(apiName);
    system.debug(sObjects.get(apiName));
}
```

---

You should be able to answer this question yourself by simply reading the `Schema` class [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm). Relevant bit:

> **getGlobalDescribe()**
>   Returns a map of all sObject names (keys) to sObject tokens (values) for the standard and custom objects defined in your organization.
>
> **Signature**
>   `public static Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> getGlobalDescribe()`
>
> **Return Value**
>   Type: `Map<String, Schema.SObjectType>`
>
> **Usage**
>   For more information, see [Accessing All sObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_global_describe.htm#apex_dynamic_global_describe).
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
> ```

---

> ### Accessing All sObjects
>
> Use the Schema `getGlobalDescribe` method to return a map that represents the relationship between all `sObject` names (keys) to `sObject` tokens (values). For example:
>
> ```
> Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
> ```
>
> The map has the following characteristics:
>
> - It is dynamic, that is, it is generated at runtime on the sObjects currently available for the organization, based on permissions.
> - The sObject names are case insensitive.
> - The keys are prefixed with the namespace, if any.*
> - The keys reflect whether the sObject is a custom object.