# Retrieving objects through soql queryin salesforce

Tags: apex, soql, query, metadata, configuration

Is it possible to retrieve all the objects present in my org using a query?

Comment: Please articulate why you think `SOQL` is the only acceptable approach.

Comment: See also: [What all is in Schema.getGlobalDescribe()?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131606/what-all-is-in-schema-getglobaldescribe)

Comment: I have a requirement to retrieve only through SOQL .I am finding whether it is possible or not

Comment: "I have a requirement" is really weak justification. What is the underlying request trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually i have a client requirement  whether it is possible to retrieve objects through SOQl without using the getGlobalDescribe() methods.

Comment: Has your client explained *why* they have this mysterious aversion to describes?

Comment: No they didn't mentioned any thing

Comment: Well, then you should solve the root problem (whatever that is) using the supported methodology (describes).

Comment: Actually i am new to salesforce. In sql it is possible  .so i am checking whether it is possible or not.

Comment: Devendra answered it already. You can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot do it using a SOQL**. You need describe call.

```
for ( Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() )
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = o.getDescribe();
    system.debug( 'Sobject:::' + objResult );
    system.debug( 'Sobject API Name:::' + objResult.getName() );
    system.debug( 'Sobject Label Name:::' + objResult.getLabel() );   
}
```

See the [Salesforce Schema Lister](http://schemalister.herokuapp.com/). This tool uses the Salesforce Metadata API to build a list of objects, fields and field attributes from within your Salesforce Org.